# The RequiresMountsFor parameter is ineffective in user-level systemd unit files

Tags: systemd, podman

I have a podman rootless container called qbittorrent. I used the *podman generate systemd* command to generate the unit file. I added the mount point I depended on after the *RequiresMountsFor* parameter and enabled the service.

```
# container-qbittorrent.service
# autogenerated by Podman 4.3.1
# Fri Dec 15 09:42:45 CST 2023

[Unit]
Description=Podman container-qbittorrent.service
Documentation=man:podman-generate-systemd(1)
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
RequiresMountsFor=/run/user/1000/containers /home/videos1

[Service]
Environment=PODMAN_SYSTEMD_UNIT=%n
Restart=on-failure
TimeoutStopSec=70
ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman start qbittorrent
ExecStop=/usr/bin/podman stop  \
        -t 10 qbittorrent
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/podman stop  \
        -t 10 qbittorrent
PIDFile=/run/user/1000/containers/vfs-containers/5cba08e37dbf6a6d5133dd132daa10c935f85c4bd1639ad0eea850a06c689c0c/userdata/conmon.pid
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

But I observed the systemd logs when the system was started and shut down and found that this had no effect. The operating system is debian 12.

I tried using system-level services, but podman’s rootless container is not compatible with the User, Group parameters in systemd unit (https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/12778)

So is there any way to make *RequiresMountsFor* work or achieve the same effect, I still want to use rootless containers.

Comment: Do not post graphics when plain text will do.

Comment: I don't think it's possible for user units to depend on system units (or vise versa). One reason could because user units are handled by the user session init, and system units by init, so they are two different sets (or sets of sets, since each user has a separate session init).

Comment: @Bib Sorry, I will edit it again later.

Comment: @muru I also guessed that it was because of this, so I didn’t know what to do.